# Rasterize point data by summing all Z values within one raster cell Python

Tags: python, csv, gis, gdal, rasterizing

I have large (~3 GB) CSV Data which holds information on timestep, lon, lat, and emissions (Z value). I would like to convert this data to raster data using Python by summing all emission values of points within a certain cell.

The pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
date                lon     lat         IMO         emission    
2015-01-01 00:05:00 5.13700 61.98248    6926622.0   0.003370
2015-01-01 00:10:00 5.13700 61.98249    6926622.0   0.003497
2015-01-01 00:15:00 5.13699 61.98249    6926622.0   0.001663
..
```

The raster is a 12kmx12km with 196 rows/cols defined LCC:

`-1275000.000  -1000000.000     12000.000     12000.000 196 196   1`

How can I do this? I checked `make_geoube` [geocube](https://corteva.github.io/geocube/stable/geocube.html#make-geocube) package, however it should be as fast as possible, because data is large and there are more files to be processed. Also i am not quite sure if it excatly does what I want.

But if so, how would I get the LCC raster to be used by geocube?

In R the [rasterize](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.4-5/topics/rasterize) function seems to do what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example or some test data?

Comment: sure, you can find a script and test data [here](https://vpro0190.proserver.punkt.de/s/2eeCBTfxMgtaD4M). I only was able to raster it on a geojson defined bounding box so far, however I would like to raster it on the abovementioned LCC grid. Also, summing the emissions would be important